# Dell XPS 15Z - 64 Bit OS not installing, but a 32 bit OS will install

Tags: 12.04, installation, 64-bit, dell, xps

I have the following system:

> Dell XPS 15Z
>   i7 Core Processor
>   16Gb of RAM
>   2Gb NVidia Card

This system is well capable of having a 64 bit OS on it. At first I thought it was just a bad image burn, but after downloading the Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.04 both 64 bit and 32 bit I have found out that the 32 bit will install with no problems. The 64 bit, however, will give me either a white small cursor which is solid not blinking and will run my system hot, or give me a Kernel Error.

I have tried this [article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z), which was although helpful in many ways, not helping in my installation issue.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Alternate CD (only aviable for 12.04 and older).